# From where can I download a precompiled Windows installable Bitcoin core with support of hardware wallet for BitBox02

Tags: multi-signature

I wanted to integrate my BitBox02 into the existing Bitcoin Core Version v24.0.1 on my Windows 10 laptop.
In the customization menu I receive the notice that this node does not contain the hardware wallet support.
From where can I now download an installable Windows 10 BitCoin Core v25 with precompiled hardware wallet support?
Kind regards
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitcoin Core does not have hardware wallet support built in. It instead makes use of external software which it calls as needed.

You can simply install Bitcoin Core as normal and set in the settings the path to the external program.

The typical external program for hardware wallet support is HWI. You can download the latest version from https://github.com/bitcoin-core/HWI/releases. Simply download and unzip the Windows binaries and place the files wherever you want. Then set the path to the `hwi.exe` file in Bitcoin Core's settings.